# Script causes “Refused to execute inline script: Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash… or a nonce is required to enable inline execution”

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, content-security-policy

I keep getting this error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: http://www.visitsingapore.com https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-V+/U3qbjHKP0SaNQhMwYNm62gfWX4QHwPJ7We1PXokI='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this and what does it mean?  My code is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data:gap: http://www.visitsingapore.com   https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
<script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/key.js"></script>
<script>$.ajax({
        url: ' http://www.visitsingapore.com/api.listing.en.json',
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('email ID', '-------@gmail.com');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('token ID', '-------');
        },
        data: {},
        success: function (qwe12) {
            var TrueResult2 = JSON.stringify(qwe12);
            document.write(TrueResult2);
        },
        error: function () { },
    });</script>
```

Comment: Is this a browser specific error?  or: is this a webkit specific security 'feature' ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The best way to fix this would be to take that `$.ajax(…)` call out of the document and move it into an external file called `ajax-call.js`, and then do the following:

```
<script src="ajax-call.js"></script>
```

The reason that’s better is, if you’re already going to the effort of setting a CSP policy for your document, then you should ideally go to the additional effort of removing all inline scripts.

But if for some reason you really *need* to keep the script inline in the document, you can change that `meta` element so the exact sha256 hash value from the error message is included as a source for the `script-src` directive, like this (with some line breaks added just for readability):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self' data:gap: http://www.visitsingapore.com 
  https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval';
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
  media-src *;
  script-src 'sha256-V+/U3qbjHKP0SaNQhMwYNm62gfWX4QHwPJ7We1PXokI='
">
```

And the following are a couple places to get a bit more information:

- [developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it)
- [www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet#Refactoring_inline_code](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Content_Security_Policy_Cheat_Sheet#Refactoring_inline_code)

Comment: I tried to make an effort to create a new js file and put the tag in the html file <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ajax-call.js"></script> but i have got another error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.visitsingapore.com/api.listing.en.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access."   what does this means?

Comment: It means the problem described in the question is solved. But you have an additional completely infrared problem than the one you describe in the question and that's answered here. So you should post a new question about the additional unrelated problem

Comment: @sideshowbarker Adding the sha256 hash value from the error worked for me, thank you

Answer (score -1):

In my case this is happen due to plugin,Plugin trying to execute some operation in website and website blocking it.
Issue is with BlazeMeter chrome plugin.

So just remove plugins and then try again.
Or
Check with another browser.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34742141)