# Content Security Policy “Refused to execute inline event handler” error

Tags: javascript, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm trying to mitigate XSS attacks by setting the Content-Security-Policy header but Chrome keeps throwing an error:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-Njg3MGUxNzkyMjViNDZkN2I3YTM3MDAzY2M0MjUxZGEzZmFhNDU0OGZjNDExMWU5OTVmMmMwMTg4NTA3ZmY4OQ=='". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I tried setting the nonce in `<script nonce="Njg3MGUxNzkyMjViNDZkN2I3YTM3MDAzY2M0MjUxZGEzZmFhNDU0OGZjNDExMWU5OTVmMmMwMTg4NTA3ZmY4OQ==" href="main.js"></script>` but it does not worked.

Here's my `Content-Security-Policy` header:

```
default-src 'none'; 
script-src 'self' 'nonce-NjJjN2E5YjA0ZDJhNDlhZjlhMDFmZjQzMjE4YzhmMTAzOWNjZjVjMGZjNDIxMWU5YWIyNGMwMTg4NTA3ZmY4OQ=='; 
connect-src 'self' https://vimeo.com; 
img-src 'self'; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; 
font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; 
media-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com; 
frame-src 'self' http://player.vimeo.com;
```

I don't like setting the `script-src` as `unsafe-inline`, as it voids the used of Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your CSP is blocking an inline event handler in your HTML code, like `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`.

Inline event handlers are bad practice (mostly because they are inline).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36349056/9847511) for insight.

Nonce [does not seem to work with inline event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400044/9847511) though. So the best thing to do would be to replace this event handler with a proper one written in your JS file.
If you cannot do that, try adding ['unsafe-hashes'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#unsafe_hashes) to your `script-src`.

Kudos for rejecting `'unsafe-inline'`, it's a shortcut we see way too often, including in production.

Comment: I am trying to avoid adding 'unsafe-inline', but inline script is blocked even when using nonce. So.. from what i see, the part of the script that is blocked (or all of it - don't know) is document.addEventListioner("load").... => Is there a way to write it in another way which is CSP compliant?

Comment: @Kosem Can't you add this code in a dedicated .js file? That's the cleanest and most straightforward approach. If you can't, as I said try using `unsafe-hashes`. Though do note that if there is dynamic data injected server side in your script before rendering (e.g. a PHP variable) you will also have to generate the hash dynamically (after it has been rendered so the variable has been replaced by its value) or the hash in your CSP won't match the one generated by the browser.

Answer (score 14):

This error can also be caused by inline styles (styles in html file inside `<style> </style>`).
I had this issue and removing inline styles solved problem.

Angular users can resolved this by setting "inlineCritical" to false for each configuration (more details  [here](https://0xdbe.github.io/AngularSecurity-DisableInlineCriticalCSS/)).

Example:

```
"configurations": {
 "production": {
   "optimization": {
     "scripts": true,
     "styles": {
       "minify": true,
       "inlineCritical": false
     },
     "fonts": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, thank's. I mean, i don't have the excpetion anymore but i'm still wondering how it really works.
I thought that by using this configuration, i could be able to delete "unsafe-inline" from "styles-src"  in  my Content Security Policy but when i do, the style doesn't render correctly on my website.
Any suggestion ?