# Cannot start vfat.tools locally - Refused to execute inline script

Tags: ethereum, content-security-policy, cryptocurrency

I followed the README instructions from vfat.tools (https://github.com/vfat-tools/vfat-tools), i.e. ran `npm install` and finally `npm run dev`. I see the following on the console:

### [Browsersync] Access URLs:

```
   Local: http://localhost:3000
External: http://192.168.0.197:3000
```

---

```
      UI: http://localhost:3001
```

### UI External: http://localhost:3001

[Browsersync] Serving files from: dist
[Browsersync] Watching files...

However, when I open localhost:3000 to access the UI, I see the following error on Chrome`s console:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy 
directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-
ACotEtBlkqjCUAsddlA/3p2h7Q0iHuDXxk577uNsXwA='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable 
inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' 
is used as a fallback.
```

Options to solve this problem include adding `unsafe-inline` somewhere in the code (for example ->  [Script causes “Refused to execute inline script: Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash… or a nonce is required to enable inline execution”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256983/script-causes-refused-to-execute-inline-script-either-the-unsafe-inline-keyw)), but I also have the impression this is not good practice.

How can I get the webpage to load properly?

Answer (score 1):

There is 3 kinds of inline scripts: `<script>...</script>`, `<a href='javascript:void(0)'` and `<a onclick='eventHandler()'`.
The first one you can resolve using `'nonce-value'` or `'hash-value'`, the last two require using of mandatory `'unsafe-inline'` (or code refactoring).

Therefore to get rid of this error you need to know which kind of inline script caused a violation.

As I can see `vfat.tools` uses [`document.getElementById("theme-button").onclick = setTheme`](https://github.com/vfat-tools/vfat-tools/blob/master/src/views/partials/theme.ejs#L36) (and maybe somewhere else something like that is used). Therefore you have to use `'unsafe-inline'` or to rewrite this part of code using `addEventListener()` function to bind an event listener.