# Chrome Extension .addEventListener never fired

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension for the first time. I have a simple button, that launches a `youtube` webpage. But I can't seem to figure out why the `button's` event listener is never fired.

The `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        button {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="youtube-button">YouTube</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("youtube-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log('clicked youtoob button!')
            window.open("https://www.youtube.com/");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `manifest`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "YouTube Button",
    "description": "A button that opens YouTube",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

The `console.log('clicked youtoob button!')` is never fired inside the developer console when I click the button.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please tell me the reason for embedding JavaScript in HTML.

Comment: There's no good reason for it. I'm not a webdeveloper and this is the first time I ever made a front end webapp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chrome console indicates that you are facing a problem similar to this [Script causes “Refused to execute inline script: Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash… or a nonce is required to enable inline execution”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256983/script-causes-refused-to-execute-inline-script-either-the-unsafe-inline-keyw).
To see your error precisely, you can right click and do 'inspect' on your button.

As indicated, the cleanest way to do this is do create a new file in your directory, called openYoutube.js for example that contains this:

```
document.getElementById("youtube-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('clicked youtoob button!')
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/");
});
```

and then call it in your html file like this

```
<script src="openYoutube.js"></script>
```

Comment: I created a file in the same directory named ```openYoutube.js```. I added it into the body tag. Still getting the same error. https://i.imgur.com/3x41Y0q.png

Comment: Edit: After clearing the error, and reloading the chrome extension it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

DevTools should have printed the following error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-HikUgQ3MQB9uiD//iKT5jDhdLF+X0toeRrwaYXjWvhY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

It is caused by embedding script in html.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        button {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="youtube-button">YouTube</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
document.getElementById("youtube-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log('clicked youtoob button!')
  window.open("https://www.youtube.com/");
});
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. https://i.imgur.com/3x41Y0q.png

Comment: Edit: After clearing the error, and reloading the chrome extension it works. Thanks for the help.